# Facebook app - Post to wall with multiple users

Tags: php, facebook

I recently made my first facebook app which works as a "connection" for posting messages to different walls. I got it all working and I now want to test it with other users. If I want a second user to be able to post to the walls through my app what needs to be added? The users can perfectly login through my php script but they are being refused when they try to post to the walls.

Should the users be added in the "Roles" section of my app? If yes, then they *have* to be "verified developers"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they posting to walls of people they are not connected to? I've got a funny feeling you can only post a status update to your own profile, otherwise the opportunities for spam would be rife. Unless you can point me elsewhere to the documentation that details otherwise?

Comment: @TommyBs: Actually it's only 1 person who needs to use this. But how to I setup another person? I don't want to ask that person to create its own app etc. This _is_ possible. Its like having a blog and connecting your facebook/twitter in order to post your threads to facebook/twitter.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, surely the other person just need to authorize your app and it should use their own access_token, user_id etc and they should be able to post. Is your app in developer mode or something similar or is it live?

Comment: The whole 'roles' and 'verified developers' thing is nothing to do with how your app will function for users.  It is purely a way to grant other facebook users different levels of access to your application.  It is used especially for sandboxed apps that are not open to the public, or for allowing more than one administrator to edit your application settings.  Could you post the login/permissions code you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out this might help you - http://thinkdiff.net/facebook-connect/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Or if you can post your code, then i can surely help you to make it available to any user to use your app to post on their walls

If the user wants to post anything to their walls using your application, then they need to grant publish_stream extended permission to your application and using their access_token, you can allow them to post anything to their walls from your application and not just one user, any number of users will be able to do it, so if you post your code, i can help you with it.

Comment: Adding the publish_stream when getting the getLoginUrl() did the trick! Thanks a lot mate. Another thing: How can I avoid that I have to login through my site every time I want to post on the wall? Can I save the access token in SQL or something?

Comment: Yes you can save access_token by adding: offline_access as extended permissions and it'll give you access_token that can be used for longer time and you can save it to your db